# check if a word consists of only three repeated characters

Tags: php

I retrieve results from a MySQL database, basically just a list of words. Occasionally a word will consist of only three repeated characters. How do I detect these words and strip off the two additional characters?

I could probably use `strlen()` to find three letter words, then explode and compare, then `substr()` to strip off the extra characters, but that seems cumbersome. Is there an easy way?

Sample data:

```
house, dog, tree, aaa, cat, computer, sss, pink
```

Expected output:

```
house, dog, tree, a, cat, computer, s, pink
```

My code so far:

```
do {
    $uterm = $row_Recordsetu['term'];
    $utermfixed = preg_replace("/(.)\1{2}/", "$0 --> $2 $1", $uterm);
    echo $utermfixed."<br>";
} while ($row_Recordsetu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Recordsetu)); ?>
```

This isn't working though. It still returns "aaa" instead of "a", for example.

Comment: There are many ways. Read on regexes. E.g.: https://regexone.com/

Comment: Is there anything you tried? We are not here to write the code for you.

Comment: Sorry. Code added. Thanks @teeyo for the effort, but I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions, this will do the trick for you :

```
(.)\1{2}
```

You can test it out here : http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lSR